# No hace la petición XMLHttprequest correctamente. Advertencia (synchronous xmlhttprequest )

Tags: javascript, json, xml, jsonobject, requests

solicito amablemente ayuda con el siguiente problema.

Dentro de una función estoy  haciendo una petición xmlhttprequest.
Luego hago xhReq.open("GET", ress, false);
Luego hago xhReq.send(null)
y por último intento gardar en jsonObject lo que retorna JSON.parse(xhReq.responseText).
A continuación muestro el pantallazo de mi código.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EL PROBLEMA ES: jsonObject no está recibiendo nada, si lo llamo en la consola, devuele *undefinded* y la variable ress si devuelve un string *json/archivo_9_3.json* . Este string se compuso concatenando variables y strings para crear la variable ress. (line 322)

La línea(324) donde hago *xhReq.open("GET", ress, false);*  Me arroja el siguiente warning. adjunto texto e imagen.
¿ Cómo soluciono esto?. 
¿ Por qué no está restornando nada?
¿Qué significa este warning?

synchronous xmlhttprequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Probaste hacerlo asyncrono al envio? En el parámetro del metodo open en vez de false pasale true. Edita esto para ver si soluciona. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por responder. Si ya lo había enviado con true, pero sigue dando un undefined. ¿Habrá otra forma de hacer estas petición? Es simplemente llamar a un archivo json, que está contenido en la carpeta "json"

Answer (score 0):

Puedes verificar el estado de la llamada de este modo:

```
xhReq.open("get",ress,true); //si quieres que sea asincrona
inreq.onreadystatechange = function (e){
if (xhReq.readyState == 4){ //se completó
  if (xhReq.status == 200){ //todo salió bien del lado del servidor
      const respuesta = JSON.parse(xhReq.response);
      console.log(respuesta);
     }
  }
}
xhReq.send(null);
```

Prueba y comentas que ocurrió. Saludos!